# Want to add a table of objects into array list

Tags: java

As I said in theme, but when I am trying to set a new object, the old ones looks    same as the last one:

```
 public class Test {

private static List<Booking> list = new ArrayList<Booking>();
private static List<Booking> lista = new ArrayList<Booking>();
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Booking[] book=new Booking[3];
    book[0]=new Booking();
    book[1]=new Booking();
    book[2]=new Booking();
    list.add(0,book[0]);
    list.add(1,book[1]);
    list.add(2,book[2]);
    list.get(0).setYear("1900");
    list.get(0).setMonth("january");
    list.get(1).setMonth("september");
    list.get(1).setYear("1600");
    list.get(2).setYear("2000");
    list.get(2).setMonth("may");
    System.out.println(list.get(0).getBook());
    System.out.println(list.get(1).getBook());
    System.out.println(list.get(2).getBook());
}

 }
```

And the booking class:

```
  public class Booking 
  {

public static String getMark()
{
    return m;
}
public static String getWym()
{
    return w;
}
public static String getWyw()
{
    return wyw;
}
public static String getImie()
{
    return imie;
}
public static String getNaz()
{
    return nazwis;
}
public static String getNr()
{
    return nr;
}
public void setMark(String m)
{
    this.m=m;
}
public void setWym(String w)
{
    this.w=w;
}
public void setWyw(String wyw)
{
    this.wyw=wyw;
}
public void setImie(String imie)
{
    this.imie=imie;
}
public void setNaz(String nazwis)
{
    this.nazwis=nazwis;
}
public void setNr(String nr)
{
    this.nr=nr;
}
public void setYear(String year)
{
    this.year=year;
}
public void setMonth(String month)
{
    this.month=month;
}
public void setDay(String day)
{
    this.day=day;
}
public void setHour(String hour)
{
    this.hour=hour;
}
public static String getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public static String getMonth()
{
    return month;
}
public static String getDay()
{
    return day;
}
public static String getHour()
{
    return hour;
}

public String getBook()
{

    String Book=getYear()+getMonth()+getDay()+getHour()+getMark()+getWym()+getWyw()+getImie()+getNaz()+getNr();
    return Book;

}
private static String year;
private static String month;
private static String day;
private static String hour;
private static String m;
private static String w;
private static String wyw;
private static String imie;
private static String nazwis;
private static String nr;
```

}

Here is what I got after compilation:

2000maynullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull

2000maynullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull

2000maynullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull

Instead of:
1900januarynullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull

1600septembernullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull

2000maynullnullnullnullnullnullnullnull

Comment: Why don't you use a constructor for Booking class?

Answer (score 4):

remove the `static` from your all your fields in `Booking`

Answer (score 2):

You are using `static` variables inside your `Booking` class and because of this all instances have common fields `year`, `month`, etc...

Making field *static* is like attaching it to whole class context not instance.

The effect is that the last modification (setting *may 2000*) is modifying all instances in result

You should make these fields non static and then instances will have their own values

```
class Booking {
    private String year;
    private String month;
    private String day;
    //another fields...

    public String getYear() {
        return this.year;
    }
    //another methods...
}
```

Also take a look at [reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) to understand usage of `static` keyword. You definitely abuse it.